# How to include a message in a BadRequestException?

Tags: java, web-services, http, jersey, jax-rs

Is it possible to include a message in a `BadRequestException` so when the user sees a response code a 400, he/she can also figure out why?

The scenario would be something like this, simplified:

```
public Entity getEntityWithOptions(@PathParam("id") String id, @QueryParam("option") String optValue) {
    if (optValue != null) {
        // Option is an enum
        try {
            Option option = Option.valueOf(optValue);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new BadRequestException(e.getMessage());
        }
        return new Entity(option);
    }
    return new Entity();
}
```

I know this can be done returning a `Response` object instead, but I wouldn't want that.

Is this possible? Maybe with an `ExceptionMapper<BadRequestException>`? Or this cannot be done since `BadRequestException` is already a Jersey-specific exception?

Comment: I think the message can be put into the constructor, right? And If an exceptionMapper is used, it actually returns a Response.

Comment: I am passing the message to the constructor, but the response is not including it.

Comment: If an exceptionMapper is used, the message passed to the constructor is displayed. Just make the mapper like this: public Response toResponse(BadRequestException e) { return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).entity(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e)).build();}

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30712454/3806701

Answer (score 6):

There is a really simple approach to this as shown below.

```
Response.ResponseBuilder resp_builder=Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST);
resp_builder.entity(e.getMessage());//message you need as the body
throw new WebApplicationException(resp_builder.build());
```

if you need to add headers, response media type or some other functionality, **ResponseBuilder** provides them all.

Answer (score 1):

You can throw a CustomException and map it to a CustomExceptionMapper to provide customized response.

```
public class CustomException extends RuntimeException {    
    public CustomException(Throwable throwable) {
        super(throwable);
    }

    public CustomException(String string, Throwable throwable) {
        super(string, throwable);
    }

    public CustomException(String string) {
        super(string);
    }

    public CustomException() {
        super();
    }
}

@Provider
public class CustomExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<CustomException> {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomExceptionMapper.class.getName());
    /**
     * This constructor is invoked when exception is thrown, after
     * resource-method has been invoked. Using @provider.
     */
    public CustomExceptionMapper() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * When exception is thrown by the jersey container.This method is invoked  
     */
    public Response toResponse(CustomException ex) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        Response.ResponseBuilder resp = Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                        .entity(ex.getMessage());

        return resp.build();
    }
}
```

Use the CustomException in your code like this.

```
public Entity getEntityWithOptions(@PathParam("id") String id, 
                                   @QueryParam("option") String optValue) 
                                   throws CustomException {
    if (optValue != null) {
        // Option is an enum
        try {
            Option option = Option.valueOf(optValue);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new CustomException(e.getMessage(),e);
        }
        return new Entity(option);
    }
    return new Entity();
}
```

Instead of message, you can also construct an object and pass it to mapper through CustomException.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom exception like this

```
public class CustomBadReq extends WebApplicationException {
     public CustomBadReq(String message) {
         super(Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
             .entity(message).type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build());
     }
}
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583973/jax-rs-jersey-how-to-customize-error-handling)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the [`BadRequestException(Response response)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/BadRequestException.html#BadRequestException-javax.ws.rs.core.Response-)constructor.

For example:

```
String msg = e.getMessage();
throw new BadRequestException(Response.status(BAD_REQUEST)
                .entity(msg).build());
```